# How can I have horizontal tabs nested under vertical tabs with jQuery.tabs()?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, tabs, nested

I am trying to nest horizontal tabs within vertical tabs with no success. The horizontals keep inheriting the attributes of their parent verticals.  I followed steps to a solution that supposedly works to no avail.

How can I have horizontal tabs nested under vertical tabs with `jQuery.tabs()`?

Please check out my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsapaka/y3JQj/) *(Note: The nested tabs start on main tab 2*).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in the CSS.

The [CSS provided by the jQuery UI site](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical) doesn't select *direct descendants*.  Their CSS is applying the vertical classes to all matches.  To be able to have a nested horizontal tabs inside of vertical tabs, you need to modify the jQuery UI classes to only select *direct descendants* by applying `>`.

That goes for the CSS in the jQuery too.

[***See working jsFiddle demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/TNyb6/)

---

### CSS

```
.ui-tabs-vertical {
    width: 55em;
}
.ui-tabs-vertical > .ui-tabs-nav {
    padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em;
    float: left;
    width: 12em;
}
.ui-tabs-vertical > .ui-tabs-nav li {
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
    border-right-width: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 -1px .2em 0;
}
.ui-tabs-vertical > .ui-tabs-nav > li > a {
    display:block;
}
.ui-tabs-vertical > .ui-tabs-nav > li.ui-tabs-active {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-right: .1em;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
}
.ui-tabs-vertical > .ui-tabs-panel {
    padding: 1em;
    float: right;
    width: 40em;
}
```

---

### jQuery

```
$(function () 
{
    $("#htabs-outer").tabs();
    
    $("#vtabs").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
    $("#vtabs > ul > li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");
    
    $("#htabs-inner").tabs();
});
```